# How to convert boost::chrono::process_cpu_clock::duration to milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++-chrono

I am using boost 1.59.0.

I am trying to use boost::chrono::process_cpu_clock to time a block of my code. I would like to report this time in milliseconds, not nanoseconds. I thought to use the duration_cast template function, although I have only found examples where it takes a single duration value as an argument, not the tuple of three values returned by process_cpu_clock.now().

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
chrono::process_cpu_clock mytimer;
const auto start = mytimer.now();
// do work
const auto duration = mytimer.now() - start;
const auto duration_msec = duration_cast<milliseconds>(duration);
```

`duration_msec` is exactly the same as `duration`; it is not converted to milliseconds.

Perhaps duration_cast isn't intended to take the process_cpu_clock::duration type as an argument; however, it compiles ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using boost namespaces instead of std? by using it explicitly here with your code it works as expected: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c40ed252075273fe